# how to make a copy-paste script with jcreator?

Tags: java

can u help me with the coding of java, so i can copy a single file using command prompt.

so, i wanna run the java file from command prompt of windows, like "java "my java script" "my file target"" and make a copy of my "my file target" at the same directory without replace the old one.

please help me?

i came out with this

```
import java.io.*;
class ReadWrite {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
        int n;
        if(args.length != 1)
            throw (new RuntimeException("Usage : java ReadWrite <filetoread> <filetowrite>"));
        while((n=fis.read()) >= 0)
            fos.write(n);
    }
}
```

but the copy of the file is named as output.txt
can u guys help me with the coding, if i wanna choose my own output name?
if i type "java ReadWrite input.txt (this is the output name that i want)" on command prompt

really need help here...

Comment: what has this got to do with jcreator?

Comment: cause i assemble the java with jcreator.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program_23{ // start of class

    public static void main(String []args){  // start of main function.

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        // decleration  ang initialization of variables
        String name = " ";
        int age  = 0;
        int no_of_hour_work = 0;
        double daily_rate = 0.0;

        // get user input
        System.out.print("Employee Name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Employee Age: ");
        age = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("No of hour(s) work: ");
        no_of_hour_work = input.nextInt();

        // compute for daily rate
        daily_rate = no_of_hour_work * 95.75;

        // display the daily rate
        System.out.print("Dialy rate:"+ daily_rate);

    }// end of main

}// end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudo-code:

```
input = open input stream for file1
output = open output stream for file 2
while (input.read() has more bytes):
    write byte to output stream
close(input, output)
```

Comment: Well if you are using args[0] to gain access to the first command line argument (the name of the input file), then it stands to reason that you could use args[1] to get access to a second command line argument and use that as the name of the output file.